# Procedimientos Almacenado de SQL Server y cómo llamarlos desde Visual Studio .NET

Tags: sql-server, asp.net

Tengo unos procedimientos almacenados de un CRUD completo en SQL server ya que en verdad, en la capa de modelo no me gustaría tener ningún tipo de consulta SQL directa.

Así que decidí trabajar con SP (Stored Procedure) y luego llamarlos declarado el `commandType` de tipo `storedProcedure`.
El problema es que tengo un error en mi código y no sé qué ocurre, se envían los parámetros a través de la función al modelo pero no me registra el archivo.

¿Qué puede estar pasando?

He aquí el código:

En esta función, lo único que hago es capturar los parámetros en un diccionario que luego se manda como parámetro a la función `send`

```
Function token() As Boolean
        Dim data As Boolean
        Dim tokenMD5 = funciones.md5(TokenKey)

        Dim parameters As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        parameters.Add("@Tabla", "Token")
        parameters.Add("@Campos", "IdUsuario,TokenKey,Tiempo")
        parameters.Add("@Valores", id.ToString & ",''" & tokenMD5.ToString & "'',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")

        data = send("spGeneric_Insert_CMS", parameters)


        Return data
    End Function
```

**Función `Send`**

Esta función se encuentra en el modelo y es la que recibe los parámetros y los envía al `stored procedure`

```
Function send(ByRef storedProcedure As String, ByRef parameters As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As Boolean
        Dim sent As Boolean = False

        comando.Connection = conexion
        comando.CommandText = storedProcedure.ToString
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        For Each param In parameters
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Key, param.Value)
        Next

        Try
            Try
                lector.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try


            comando.ExecuteNonQuery()


            sent = True
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try


        Return sent

    End Function
```

Ahora, yo sé que la función recibe los parámetros correctamente ya que en el `foreach` ejecuto en un `MsgBox` el `key` y el `value` recibido y todo va bien, pero la función como tal me retorna `false`, es decir no me registra el valor.

Answer (score 1):

ya logre resolver mi error, no era mas que un error de sintaxis

El error se encontraba aqui

```
Function token() As Boolean
        Dim data As Boolean
        Dim tokenMD5 = funciones.md5(TokenKey)

        Dim parameters As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        parameters.Add("@Tabla", "Token")
        parameters.Add("@Campos", "IdUsuario,TokenKey,Tiempo")
        parameters.Add("@Valores", id.ToString & ",'" & tokenMD5.ToString & "',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP") ' EN ESTA LINEA SE ENCONTRABA EL ERROR

        data = send("spGeneric_Insert_CMS", parameters)


        Return data
    End Function
```

Resulta que estaba enviando un parametro con dos comillas simples ('') y solo era una.